# problema .json / javascript

Tags: javascript, json, fetch

estoy tratando de hacer un modelo de cajero automático, donde aparezcan botones en la pantalla con números de cuenta y al cliquear muestre saldo y que tipo de cuenta es. el codigo de javascript seria el siguiente:

```
fetch('/JS/data.json')
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((data) => {
    console.log(data);
    if (Array.isArray(data)) {
      const cuentasFiltradas = data.filter(cuentas => cuentas.moneda === "$" || cuentas.moneda === "u$s");
      const cuentasMostradas = cuentasFiltradas.filter(cuentas => cuentas.tipo_letras === "CA" || cuentas.tipo_letras === "CC");

      const mostrarCuentas = (cuentas) => {
        const cuentasContainer = document.getElementById("cuentas-container");
        cuentasContainer.innerHTML = "";
        console.log(mostrarCuentas);

        cuentas.forEach(cuentas => {
          const button = document.createElement("button");
          button.innerText = `${cuentas.tipo_letras} - ${cuentas.n}`;
          button.addEventListener("click", () => mostrarInformacionCuenta(cuentas));

          cuentasContainer.appendChild(button);
        });
      };


//informacion de la cuenta


      const mostrarInformacionCuenta = (cuentas) => {
        const informacionContainer = document.getElementById("informacion-container");
        informacionContainer.innerHTML = "";
        console.log(informacionContainer);
        const saldo = document.createElement("p");
        saldo.innerText = `Saldo: ${cuentas.saldo}`;

        const tipoCuenta = document.createElement("p");
        tipoCuenta.innerText = `Tipo de Cuenta: ${cuentas.tipo_letras}`;

        const numeroCuenta = document.createElement("p");
        numeroCuenta.innerText = `Número de Cuenta: ${cuentas.n}`;

        informacionContainer.appendChild(saldo);
        informacionContainer.appendChild(tipoCuenta);
        informacionContainer.appendChild(numeroCuenta);
      };



      console.log(cuentasFiltradas)
      mostrarCuentas(cuentasMostradas);
    } else {
      console.log("Error: Los datos obtenidos no están en el formato esperado.");
    }
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log("Error al obtener los datos de la API:", error);
  });
```

deberia mostra botones con los numeros de cuenta, y no esta apareciendo nada, en la consola no aparece ningun error.
que estoy haciendo mal? gracias.

Comment: Agrega un ejemplo de `data.json`